# Bash: AWK - $1 as first parameter of shell script

Tags: bash, unix, parameters, awk

I spent on this 2 hours and get nothing. I want to get $1 and $2 as a first command line input of shell script, but I couldn't manage this. And $3 and $0 would be columns in awk. I try different methods but nothing works for me.

```
awk -F':' -v  "limit=1000" '{ if ( $3 >=limit ) gsub("~/$1/",~/$2/); print \$0}' file.txt
```

Comment: can you give an example of what is in file.txt?

Answer (score 2):

the cleanest method is to explicitly pass the values from shell to awk with awk's `-v` option:

```
awk -F: -v limit=1000 -v patt="~/$1/" -v repl="~/$2/" '
    $3 >=limit {gsub(patt,repl); print}
' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 for doing the string concatenation in the shell before setting the `awk` variables.

Comment: Thanks to all you guys! It's now clear for me. I'm sorry not to post my expected output, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any sample input or expected output so this is a guess but you probably want something like this:

```
awk -F':' -v limit=1000 -v arg1="$1" -v arg2="$2" '$3 >= limit{gsub("~/" arg1 "/","~/" arg2 "/"); print}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When your awk line is part of a script file, and you want to use $1 and $2 from the script in your awk command, you should temporary stop the literal string with a single quote and start it again.

```
awk -F':' -v  "limit=1000" '{ if ( $3 >=limit ) gsub("~/'$1'/",~/'$2'/); print $0}' file.txt
```

Comment: In case the shell parameters contain weird whitespace, you need to quote the shell variables (and the awk string literals): `gsub("~/"'"$1"'"/","~/"'"$2"'"/")` -- pretty messy.

Comment: @glennjackman is right. Absolutely do NOT do what is suggested in this answer, there are much simpler and more robust ways to pass the value of shell variables to awk scripts.

Comment: I tried to exlain why Smugli spent 2 hours on this and get nothing.
All the quotes needed is making everything messy and hard to debug.
Personally I would prefer using a while loop with IFS : and avoid awk, but I thought that is beside the question.